# Dynamically Create HTML Table with Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asynchronous, pagination

I'm trying to create an html table with pagination. I'm requesting JSON data via $.get call using JQuery which is an async call. The solution I currently have duplicates the HTML code whenever a new page is selected. I know this is an asynchronocity but I'm not exactly sure what the best method to overcome this would be.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function generateTable(currentPage) {
        this.URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts";
        $.getJSON(URL, function(data) { 
            const pages = Math.ceil(data.length / 10); 

            for(let i = currentPage*10; i<(currentPage*10)+10; i++ ) {
                let post = data[i]; 
                let tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + post.userId + "</td>" + "<td>" + post.id + "</td>" + "<td>" + post.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + post.body + "</td>" + "</tr>"
                $(tblRow).appendTo("#jsonData tbody");
            }
            for (let i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
                let pagingHtml = "<a href=# onclick=generateTable("+(i-1)+")>"+" "+i+" "+"</a>" 
                $(pagingHtml).appendTo("#paging"); 
            }
        })
    }
    generateTable(0); 

</script>
```

Comment: why dont you use [**`datatables`**](https://datatables.net/) and add the JSON data to it and let it handle the pagination itself

Comment: The specifications for the assignment requires me to solve this using vanilla Javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before populating the HTML, clear out the current rows from the page:

```
$("#jsonData tbody,#paging").empty();
```

This assumes that those two parent elements only have dynamic content. If not, you should reference container elements that *only* have dynamic content (so no headers, footers, ...etc).